# Populate DataGridView with 2 columns from list

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to bind a list of items to a `DataGridView`. The problem is that it shows all columns in the list, and I want to show just 2 of them and keep the others(maybe to make them invisible), because they contain some IDs important for the logic behind. This is what I have so far:

```
private void BindFormData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //returns a list of items
    var extraParamters = context.getExtraParameters(scheduleId, exportId);

    if (extraParamters.Count > 0)
    {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = extraParamters;
    }
}
```

The list of items looks like:

```
Id | accId | Name | Value | custId | 
 1    150    Name    15      10
 2    200    Name    25      10
```

And so on..

How do I show just the `Name` and the `Value` columns? My idea is that I'll have them editable in the `DataGridView`, and that I'll also be able to insert new entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your grid view auto generate the columns, and then just remove them.

- you can also build it all in code, though this might be easier for you until you get used to it.

So something like this:

```
 dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
 dataGridView1.DataSource = extraParamters;
 dataGridView1.Columns.Remove("accId");
 dataGridView1.Columns.Remove("custId");
 dataGridView1.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
```

Notice I didn't remove the `id` column - just hid it. You'll be needed that one for your updating in the future.

Or just hide the ones you don't want

```
 dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
 dataGridView1.DataSource = extraParamters;
 dataGridView1.Columns["accId"].Visible = false;
 dataGridView1.Columns["custId"].Visible = false;
 dataGridView1.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
```

Comment: i am using winforms, and this is for asp.net.

Comment: Sorry - just noticed. Re-doing it now

Comment: Thank you, it should be working, but when it gets to the place where I set the column name(no matter if hiding or removing) it directly loads the form, like it can't find the column name in the list.. E.g. here `dataGridView1.Columns["accId"].Visible = false;` And then the DataGridView is empty.

Comment: put a break point in place and inspect your datasource to ensure the names match perfectly. You can also reference the column by (zero-based) index too - so `dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;` would hide the first column.

Comment: Also double check your project to make sure you don't have anything else overriding this code that could be getting fired after yours. Check the design view to make sure it's not referencing anything els.e

Comment: It works fine now, I have missed to set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to true. I'm sorry it's my bad. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: That's ok bud, it happens :) Glad it's all working now.